# Is there a good secular equivalent of "God be With you"?

Tags: phrase-requests

A co-worker is leaving for an urgent emergency trip home.  No details, but sounds like a family member is very ill and might die.  So "have fun" and even "hope it goes well" are out...there's no chance it's going to be fun, and unlikely to end well.  But I'd like to be supportive. "God be with you" would suit for its broad supportive-ness  and no expectations of fun and prizes, but neither of us ever use religious language in our conversations,  so it feels fake to me to bring God into it.   Any thoughts?

Comment: "Best wishes", "All the best", "Look after yourself", "I'll be thinking of you"

Comment: "You will be in my thoughts."

Comment: Marx be with you? Or just "For success!" followed by a shot of vodka.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't say "Goodbye"!

Comment: “Hoping all goes well”.

Answer (score 2):

Expressing your concern is a great thing to do. Don't worry about sounding lame. A friend will understand where your heart is.

James Random has offered a few suggestions. Here are a few more:

- "Your family will appreciate having you near" - shows you understand the importance of what they are doing.
- "My thoughts are with you and your family"
- "Let me know if you need someone to listen"
- "Remember, you are not alone"
- "Don't worry about anything here at work while you are gone. Family comes first"

If something lighter is appropriate:

- I'm pulling for you
- I'm on your team